# Pandas - create a tuple of the most frequent words using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a dataframe  with columns :languages and words

```
df:
      Parts of speech  word
    0 Noun             cat
    1 Noun             water
    2 Noun             cat
    3 verb             draw
    4 verb             draw
    5 adj              slow
```

I want to group the top words by parts of speech(what i expect):

```
Parts of speech     top 
Noun             {'cat':2,'water':1}
verb             {'draw':2}
adj              {'slow':1}
```

I do it using the method groupby and apply, but I don 't get what I need

```
df2=df.groupby('Parts of speech')['word'].apply(lambda x : x.value_counts())
```

How do I create a tuple for each parts of speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to aggregate using [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) + [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
df2=df.groupby('Parts of speech')['word'].agg(Counter)
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
Parts of speech
Noun    {'cat': 2, 'water': 1}
adj                {'slow': 1}
verb               {'draw': 2}
Name: word, dtype: object
```

Alternative using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) (notice the to_dict call at the end):

```
df2 = df.groupby('Parts of speech')['word'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
```